# BootStrap media object

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am learning BootStrap and facing a bit difficulty in media objects. I want to create a simple container with image on left and text on right. I don't know why as soon as my content exceeds 1 line, the entire media-body goes in a [new block beneath image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adXO0.png). Is there a way to fix this ? I want pic to always be on left and media-body always on right no matter the number of lines in text. I am sorry if this has been answered already but it will help me a lot if someone can guide me

Comment: Iit would be great if you could share a portion of your HTML and CSS code, pertaining to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think i got your Question, You can try this instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="media">
            <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/2/100/100.jpg?hmac=Y2da7WhwSnMn7y41c8WEc1ZO_AGIhVD3zTzghi4-Hiw" class="mr-3" alt="...">
            <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
            <p>Will you do the same for me? It's time to face the music I'm no longer your muse. Heard it's beautiful, be the judge and my girls gonna take a vote. I can feel a phoenix inside of me. Heaven is jealous of our love, angels are crying from up above. Yeah, you take me to utopia.Will you do the same for me? It's time to face the music I'm no longer your muse. Heard it's beautiful, be the judge and my girls gonna take a vote. I can feel a phoenix inside of me. Heaven is jealous of our love, angels are crying from up above. Yeah, you take me to utopia.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Plz find the codepen url here https://codepen.io/azaharmohd/pen/abEYqwa